# redirect from output file so can be captured

Tags: r, bash, io-redirection

A program `foo` writes to an output file and prints diagnostic information to `stdout`.

Thus:

```
foo -o ./out  -i ./input  > log
```

results in the valuable stuff in `./out` and some mumbo jumbo in `log`.

I need to read `./out` into another program (an `R` script I am writing).

The intermediate step of writing to file `./out` and reading again is slow, and I need to do this for big `./out` files, hundreds of times.

I would like to perform some kind of redirection so that `foo` writes to a file descriptor rather than a file `./out`, which I can read into my script directly. But `stdout` is already used.

Here is what I tried:

in `R`:

```
library(data.table)
fread(cmd = "foo -o /dev/stdout -i ./input > /dev/null")
```

but I get an error:

```
  File '/data1/tmp/RtmpkKIpBm/fileeb789130da8e3' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

Comment: You may try this in bash: `foo -o >(your_R_script) -i ./input > log`

Comment: good idea @M.NejatAydin, but I am actually calling the bash command from within the R script...

Comment: I've overlooked that. I'm not familiar with `R`. Is the error you got from `R` or from `foo` ? Perhaps you may try `-o -` while calling `foo`. It looks like to me the error is from the line `library(data.table)`

Answer (score 1):

```
foo -o >(cat)  -i ./input  > log
```

Demo:

```
$ cat foo 
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "-o" ]; then
    exit 2
fi
echo "mumbo jumbo stdout" >&1
echo "valueable info" > "$2"
echo "mumbo jumbo stderr" >&2 # threw in stderr for good measure
$ ./foo -o x
mumbo jumbo stdout
mumbo jumbo stderr
$ cat x
valueable info
$ rm x
$ ./foo -o /dev/stdout
mumbo jumbo stdout
valueable info
mumbo jumbo stderr
$ ./foo -o /dev/stdout &>/dev/null
$ ./foo -o >(cat) &>/dev/null
valueable info
```

Explanation:

Every process has its own stdout. with `./foo -o /dev/stdout &>/dev/null`, you're telling `foo` to output its valuable info into its own stdout, which is `/dev/null`. But with `./foo -o >(cat) &>/dev/null`, you're telling `foo` to output its valuable info into some pipe, and that pipe goes to `cat`, whose stdout is not `/dev/null`, but rather inherited from the shell.

In the demo, the shell's stdout is the terminal, but if it was coming from R's `fread()`, both the shell's stdout and `cat`'s stdout would go to where `fread()` can read them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foo -o /dev/fd/3 -i ./input 3>&1 1>/dev/null
```

- Redirections are processed before commands are run
- Redirections are processed left-to-right
- `3>&1` causes anything written to file descriptor 3 to go to the current `stdout`
- `1>/dev/null` causes anything written to `stdout` to go to `/dev/null`
- Writing to `/dev/fd/3` then writes to the original `stdout`
- The code should work with any POSIX-compliant shell on any system that supports the `/dev/fd` directory.
- The `/dev/fd` directory is not part of POSIX, but it is supported on many Unix-like systems, including Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, and Solaris.